# Convert TSV to CSV, where TSV field has commas in it

Tags: sed

I have a TSV with fields that look like:

```
name   location   1,2,3,4,5
```

When I use `sed 's/\w/,/g'` 
i end up with a csv where 1,2,3,4 and 5 are considered seperate entrys. 
I would like it to be `'1 2 3 4 5'`
I've tried converting commas to white space before running the above command using

```
sed 's/,/\w/g'
```

however when converting the whitespace back to commas it includes single white spaces as well as the tabs, so what is the regex for just a single whitespace character?

Desired output:

```
name, location,1 2 3 4 5,
```

Comment: Are you sure the input file is tab-separated, or is it just a bunch of spaces

Comment: In my text editor (sublime text) they look like tabs

Comment: separators in CSV values are usually handled by enclosing the values in quotes, e.g. `name,location,"1,2,3,4,5"`. Would you consider such a solution acceptable?

Comment: Yeah that would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned in a comment CSV usually deals with occurences of its separator character in values by enclosing the value in quotes, so I suggest you simply deal with this by enclosing every value in quotes :

```
sed -E 's/([^\t]*)(\t|$)/"\1",/g'
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/UzkjVv).

This leaves a trailing comma as in your sample output, if you want to avoid it you can use the following :

```
sed -E 's/\t+$//;s/^/"/;s/\t/","/g;s/$/"/'
```

If your original data contains `"` you will however need to escape those, which you can achieve by adding the following substitution before the other(s) :

```
s/"/\\"/g
```

As [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/) suggests we can also strip the trailing empty fields :

```
s/\t+$//
```

In conclusion I'd use the following :

```
sed -E 's/"/\\"/g;s/\t+$//;s/^/"/;s/\t/","/g;s/$/"/'
```

which you can try [here](https://ideone.com/1qFA83).

Comment: @EdMorton the trailing comma was in OP's sample output and my answer mentions it and offers an alternative. I fixed the two other problems though.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even notice the OP wanted to change all his commas to blanks within that last field either! What you have now is better but it'd remove any empty field at the end of a line.

Comment: I just voted this up and then noticed that the resulting CSV broke jquery-csv. After much searching, I found out you need to escape the double quote with *another double quote*! The resulting command would thus be `sed -E 's/"/""/g;s/\t+$//;s/^/"/;s/\t/","/g;s/$/"/'`, which worked well for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Either replace tabs with `","` and enclose lines between double quotes, or replace commas with spaces and tabs with commas. In both cases you'll get valid CSV.

```
$ cat file
name    location        1,2,3,4,5
$
$ sed 's/\t/","/g; s/^\|$/"/g' file
"name","location","1,2,3,4,5"
$
$ sed 's/,/ /g; s/\t/,/g' file
name,location,1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

And in awk:

```
$ awk -v OFS="," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/,/)$i="\"" $i "\"";$1=$1}1' file
name,location,"1,2,3,4,5"
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -v OFS="," '{          # output delimiter to a comma *
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)       # loop all fields
        if($i~/,/)           # if comma in field
            $i="\"" $i "\""  # surround with quotes **
    $1=$1                    # rebuild record
}1' file                     # output
```

* if there is space in the record, consider input field separator to a tab with  `awk -F"\t"`.

** also, if there are quotes in the fields with commas, maybe they should be duplicated or escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your real requirements:

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS=',' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i="\""$i"\""} 1' file
"name","location","1,2,3,4,5"

$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS=',' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(OFS," ",$i); $1=$1} 1' file
name,location,1 2 3 4 5

$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS=',' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(OFS," ",$i); $(NF+1)=""} 1' file
name,location,1 2 3 4 5,

$ echo 'a"b' | awk -F'\t' -v OFS=',' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { gsub(/"/,"\"\"",$i); $i="\""$i"\"" } } 1'
"a""b"
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/\t/","/g; s/^\|$/"/g' file` 
doesn't work in MacOS

Instead use
`sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/' file`  for  MacOS.